# How to enable Gzip compression in flask?

Tags: flask, heroku, gzip, html-compression

I have deployed a flask app using heroku. I want to enable gzip compression in it. Usually the tutorials and videos on the youtube show gzip compression for php, wordpress and apache server but how can we do it if we are deploying a flask app using heroku

Comment: You can use the [Flask Compress](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Compress/) package.